# Batch file looping with ""

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to loop through a text file like this :

```
"11/05/2016",Paris,Snowy,02
N/A,February,London,15
"11/05/2016",Berlin,Sunny,25
```

to make it look like this:

```
2016/11/05,Paris,Snowy,02
N/A,London,Rainy,15
2016/11/05,Berlin,Sunny,25
```

I'm stuck with

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3* delims=,/" %%G IN (weather.txt) DO @echo %%I %%G %%H %%J
```

any idea please ?

Comment: Why use `/` as a delimiter?

Comment: You need to add the characters that you delimit on back in to your echoing. `@echo %%I\%%G\%%H,%%J,%%K,%%L` and change `tokens` to `1-6`.

Comment: @ThomasWeller to put 2016 in the first place, but it makes problems with N/A and doesn't resolve the "" problem.

Comment: `FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3* delims=," %%G IN (weather.txt) DO @echo %%~I,%%~G,%%~H,%%~J`  ?

Comment: I didn't notice the quotes. Use this as a string - `tokens^=1-3^ delims^=^,/^"` with no enclosing quotes. We escape all delimiting characters so don't need it enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=," %%G IN ("weather.txt") DO (
  FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%g IN ("%%~G") DO (
    if "%%~i"=="" (
      rem N/A                 input -> output
      echo(%%~G,%%~H
    ) else (
      rem 11/05/2016          input
      echo(%%i/%%g/%%h,%%H
      rem 2016/11/05          output
    )
  )
)
```

Token templates in `%%G` and `%%g` loops are as follows:

```
G            H
"11/05/2016",Paris,Snowy,02
 g  h  i

G   H
N/A,London,Rainy,15
g h                     3rd token (%%i) is empty
```